# AND operator in nested ifelse function

Tags: r, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm not an advanced R user but normally soon or later I find the help I need.
Well, not this time.
I have a data frame called "df" and I'm trying to create an extra column "Sel" where to store information based on other columns info.
To do that I used a nested ifelse function, below is the code I used, it works for the first two conditions but not for the second two conditions where I use the AND operator.
I don't see any difference where comparing the usage to other examples, and I don't get errors, only the statement relative to that condition is not pasted/printed. (I've also tried &&).
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
df <- data.frame(
  Gene = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  P_a = c(NA, NA, 21010, 14941,12),
  E_a = c(NA, NA, "miss_b", "miss_b",NA),
  P_b = c(1,200,32,NA,21),
  E_b = c(NA, NA, "miss_a", NA,"miss_a"),
  Eq = c("no", "yes", NA, NA,NA )
  )
```

```
df$Sel <- ifelse(
  (df$Eq == "no"), "same",
  ifelse((df$Eq == "yes"), "diff",
         ifelse (df$E_a == "miss_b" & 
                 df$E_b == "miss_a", "G_P",
                    ifelse(is.na(df$P_b & df$E_b &
                                df$Eq),"in","out"
                                                      ))))
```

This is the result_df that I would expect to generate with my code

```
df_result <- data.frame(
  Gene = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  P_a = c(NA, NA, 21010, 14941,12),
  E_a = c(NA, NA, "miss_b", "miss_b",NA),
  P_b = c(1,200,32,NA,21),
  E_b = c(NA, NA, "miss_a", NA,"miss_a"),
  Eq = c("no", "yes", NA, NA, NA ),
  Sel = c("same","diff", "G_P","in", "out")
)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please don't post pictures of data because we cannot copy/paste those values for testing.

Comment: I know you are completely right. I will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your modified code.

```
df$Sel <- ifelse(
  (df$Eq %in% "no"), "same",
  ifelse((df$Eq %in% "yes"), "diff",
         ifelse (df$E_a %in% "miss_b" & 
                   df$E_b %in% "miss_a", "G_P",
                 ifelse(is.na(df$P_b) & is.na(df$E_b) &
                                is.na(df$Eq),"in","out"
                 ))))


df$Sel 
[1] "same" "diff" "G_P"  "in"   "out"
```

The first problem was the use of `==`. As long as you have no NA in your data `==` works perfectly. But if you use `NA` with `==` you will get an NA as result - not a desired FALSE or TRUE. And `ifelse` needs a logical (`FALSE, TRUE`) otherise you will just get NA as result. That happend in your third row, like you mentioned.

You can try this as an example `ifelse(3 == NA, 1, 2)`. You might expect 2 as output, because 2 is not NA. But you get NA as output.

Instead of `==` use `%in%`.

The second problem was in `is.na(df$P_b & df$E_b & df$Eq)`. You can only put one variable at a time in `is.na()`. Therefore every variable needs an own `is.na`function - `ifelse(is.na(df$P_b) & is.na(df$E_b) & is.na(df$Eq),"in","out")`.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for the modifications in the code and for the exhaustive explanation.